# PHP Why can't initialize static variable to time()?

Tags: static, initialization

I received error when set static variable initial value to time().

The error message is *"**syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in **[...][...]** on line 7**"*

```
<?php 
define("DEBUG", true);
define("NEWLINE", "<br>");
...
function debugMsg($msg) {
    static $lastTime = time();
    if(DEBUG==true) echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())." ".$msg." (".(time()-$lastTime)." seconds)".NEWLINE;
    $lastTime = time();
}
?>

debugMsg("XXX task completed");
//My expected output like below:
//2015-05-01 15:04:47 XXX task completed (2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHP Documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> Static variables may be declared as seen in the examples above. Trying to assign values to these variables which are the result of expressions will cause a parse error.

You are trying to assign a value to a variable which is the result of an expression

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed my code to static $lastTime = START_TIME; where START_TIME is defined at beginning of code define("START_TIME", time());